# SharePoint 2013 background creation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, settings, site-settings

Is it possible to create a background in SharePoint 2013 but not have it show up as a psuedo-transparent/watermark style background?  I have an image that I'd like to use that have rich colors, but when I try to use it, the background image is almost transparent.

Appreciate any help you can provide!!

Comment: I hope it works for you.. If not than please share it here so i can help you on it more.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the background image using below mentioned CSS.

```
body.ms-backgroundImage {
   background: url(insert image file here) !important;
}
```

To remove the transparency from the background image you can use below mentioned CSS

```
.ms-core-overlay {
   /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"BackgroundOverlay")] */ background-color:rgba( 255,255,255,1 ) !important;
}
```

You can get the proper instructions from below given URL.

[Site background – Class: ms-backgroundImage](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-css-classes-that-suck-and-save-the-day/)

Comment: Please check this as well...http://paulryan.com.au/2015/sharepoint-online-supporting-high-resolution-background-images/

Comment: Thank you!  Is it dumb to ask where I would insert that CSS language?  Just in a content editor web part?

Comment: If you want it for a specific page then YES but if you want it for entire site than you need to add it to master page (add to css file & reference it to master page).

Comment: I added added the following to a content editor web part under "edit source":

body.ms-backgroundImage {
   background: url(PLACED LINK HERE);
}
.ms-core-overlay {
   /* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"BackgroundOverlay")] */ background-color:rgba( 255,255,255,1 );
}

Nothing happened.  I am fairly new to the CSS game.  Any thoughts?

Comment: so for that page it will work for you. Please don't forget to put **!important** after CSS attribute.

Comment: Please check updated code for use of **!important** in CSS.

Comment: is it worked for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: 1. Add content editor web part
2. Paste the 2 lines of code you provided (ensuring that the picture link is included)
3. Save
4. No change

Comment: You should check the class names for your body background if it is applied or not.